# Cannot boot Fedora from Ubuntu GRUB menu in multi boot system

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

On my computer I have 3 operating systems: Windows 10, Ubuntu and Fedora. After turning on the computer I see this:

[image: Grub customizer screen shot]

The system that turns on first is Ubuntu, and it gives me chance to choose system I would like to use (on attached image). The links for Ubuntu and Windows work fine, but I can't boot Fedora (which I installed lately) from this menu. Instead of one link called "fedora" as it should be, I have a lot of lines with EFI/fedora/..., and none of them works. To boot fedora I must go through the firmware boot menu, which is quite inconvenient.

Fedora works fine once it boots, so the problem is with Ubuntu's GRUB. I tried to use grub customizer on fedora, but it does not see Ubuntu, only Windows.

How can I fix GRUB to boot my Fedora installation as well as Ubuntu and Windows?

Comment: is this about Ubuntu or Fedora?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is here - is it that you can't boot Fedora from GRUB (presumably Ubuntu's GRUB) although there's nothing wrong with the Fedora installation itself?

Comment: Hi, the question is about Ubuntu, because this is the system that boots first and gives me chance to choose from 3 I have installed. Problem is, that I can not choose fedora, because instead of one link called "fedora" I have a lot of lines called EFI/fedora/... (on attached image) and none of them works properly.                                                                                               Only chanse to turn on fedora is to go through boot menu, which is quite inconvenient. I have no idea how to fix this, so I hope maybe someone delt with similar problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying your question and editing it. I agree it's about Ubuntu and I've voted to reopen, but one thing that you can do that might help us figure out the problem would be to run  [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and post a link in your question to the info summary. Don't click recommended repair, just get the info for now.

Comment: Depending on how you installed Fedora, you may need to mount your Fedora partition before running `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu. You also may need to add drivers for LVM, if you used LVM for Fedora, but not Ubuntu, `sudo apt install lvm2`. Most that dual boot use a standard partition as LVM's advantage is when you have full drive as LVM.

Comment: @Zanna [link to boot repair info] (http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tSKJGtVfzp/)

Comment: @oldfred I have installed fedora using default setting, I was just clicking NEXT and didn't change anything. I've done upgrade-grub, didn't change anything, second command gave result "lvm2 is already the newest version"

Comment: Did you try mounting the Fedora partition(s) in LVM and then run `sudo update-grub`? You also can add a configfile entry to use Fedora's UEFI entry or chainload like Windows to Fedora's EFI. It looks like Boot-Repair mounted LVM, but also said your Windows was still hibernated.

Comment: @oldfred As I see via File manager, fedora partitions are already mounted.
About second option could you be more precise how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Now saw you have proxy files. Those are from Grub Customizer. You should either stay with Grub Customizer. But if it does not do what you want, totally reinstall grub2, so Grub Customizer is uninstalled. You may want to backup any custom settings in 40_custom that you already have done, otherwise those get overwritten.

You can try this in 40_custom:

```
menuentry "Fedora UEFI" {
  search --file --no-floppy --set=root 26F5-18E3
  chainloader (${root})/efi/fedora/grub.cfg
}
```

Or a configfile entry that loads Fedora's grub since it is in a separate /boot that is not inside the LVM. May be grub.conf not grub.cfg with Fedora.

```
menuentry "Fedora configfile" {
  search --file --no-floppy --set=root e5cbe847-a1be-4eee-a35a-e59fca2ec794
  configfile (${root})/boot/grub/grub.cfg
}
```

All the examples I have for booting Fedora directly do not use LVM, so I do not know details on the mount in grub of the LVM. If LVM mounted your grub update should find it and add a direct boot of  the fedora install. You may need to add the loading of lvm modules into grub also using `insmod lvm`

Another alternative is just copy the boot stanza from Fedora's grub into Ubuntu's 40_custom, its just then you have to regularly update when Fedora has kernel update.

Comment: Any idea how to make this work with secure boot turned on?

Comment: Secure boot uses shimx64.efi not grubx64.efi and signed kernels & drivers. Not sure what else may be required.